# SSJS variable not being passed to JSON payload

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, api, ssjs

I am trying to do an API call. I am getting a query string parameter from a URL and attempting to pass it into a JSON payload for an API call. However, it looks like the value in the variable is not being passed into the JSON payload. But if I were have a static string in the variable, the call works.

For context, what I am doing is creating an email on the fly, pass the email name to another page which then I need to retrieve the legacy ID to perform a triggered send. I am able to do everything up to retrieving the legacy ID from the email name being passed from the previous page. I hope this is clear.

Here is my code:

```
    var email_name = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("email_name");
    var auth = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
    
    email_name = String(email_name);
    Write("<br><br> Email Name: " + email_name + "<br><br>"); //The email name being passed from the form does get written successfully.

    var url = 'https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/query'

    var payload = {
      "page": {
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 50
      },
      "query": {
        "leftOperand": {
          "property": "name",
          "simpleOperator": "equal",
          "value": email_name // Here is the variable from above but seems to not be working
        },
        "logicalOperator": "AND",
        "rightOperand": {
          "property": "assetType.name",
          "simpleOperator": "equal",
          "value": "htmlemail"
        }
      },
      "fields": [
        "data"
      ]
    };

    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;
    req.contentType = "application/json"
    req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
    req.method = "POST";
    req.postData = Stringify(payload);

    var resp = req.send();

    var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));
    var legacyId = resultJSON.items[0].data.email.legacy.legacyId;

    Write("<br><br> Legacy ID: " + legacyId + "<br><br>"); // This shows up as undefined
```

However if I were to change the `email_name` variable from the `Request.GetQueryStringParameter` to just the string of the name of email, the call works and gets the legacy ID correctly.

Any advice?

Edit: if I were to append the email name to the URL in a query string, I am able to request it and successfully make the API call. It's just when I pass it from one form to the other, I can't use it in the payload.

Comment: Your [simpleoperator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/simpleoperators.html) values are incorrect -- `equal` should be `equals`.

Comment: I'd also recommend building this in Postman first -- then converting to SSJS.  It's much easier to iterate in postman than it is to test SSJS in a CloudPage or in a Script Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `GetQueryStringParameters`, use `GetFormField` ([details here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_utilitiesGetFormField.html)).